# How to make event calling holder class function

Tags: c#, .net, xna

This may have been asked several times, but I don't know what to search for..

Anyway. I have a class called Character. Inside of it I want to have a collision component that I have called RectangleCollision. Inside of it there is a function called IsOverlapping that checks for overlap.

I want to have a function that can be modified for each game object. For example create a function called OnBeginOverlap(); that will fire everytime the collision component detects a collision.

Is there any way that I can bind this function as delegate or event? Or something?

Comment: Each game object may be based on a common class and the CollisionHandling function may be declared as virtual in the base class and overriden in its derived classes. Google on object programming, i.e. "inheritance polymophism".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read about events and delegates. There are plenty of examples on the web. The easiest I managed to find when I was trying to understand the subject was this:

[The Simplest C# Events Example Imaginable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable)

You can also check out the below (you can compile this as console application):

```
class Character
{

    public delegate void OverlappingHandler(Character character, EventArgs e);
    public event OverlappingHandler OverlappingEvent;
    public void IsOverlapping()
    {
        bool overlapping = true;

        if (overlapping)
        {
            if (OverlappingEvent != null)
            {
                OverlappingEvent(this, null);
            }
        }
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Character c = new Character();
        c.OverlappingEvent += OverlappingEventHandler;
        c.OverlappingEvent += OverlappingSecondEventHandler;

        c.IsOverlapping();

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void OverlappingEventHandler(Character character, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We have overlapping here!!");
    }

    static void OverlappingSecondEventHandler(Character character, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Seriously, we have overlapping !!");
    }
}
```

So step by step:

1. Create a delegate, which is a bridge between your event and the code you want to run when event is triggered. You give parameters to a delegate, which are (object sender, EventArgs e) - in this example sender is the Character class, arguments are used to send additional info - for example type of character.
2. Create event of our delegate type
3. In our function IsOverlapping() there would be your logic checking if there is overlapping happening. If there is, you fire up event. You should check first if there is anything connected to the event  (hence the if (OverlappingEvent != null)) - if some there is something, fire up the event.
4. In the Main() you create an instance of the class and...
5. Subscribe your event handlers to it, so the code that should be executed when the event is triggered. I connected two methods, just to show that you can subscribe more than one.
6. Now when you run c.IsOverlapping() this is what happens:

   - your logic to check overlapping runs,
   - if there is overlapping, there will be a check if OverlappingEvent has code subscribed (it does in Main()),
   - if it does event will be triggered,
   - code subscribed to the event runs - in this case your code in Main().

You can compile this as console app and it will display 2 lines:

> We have overlapping here!!
>
> Seriously, we have overlapping !!

Hope this helps.